# Is it possible to select multiple files in Kivy with a rectangle select?

Tags: python, kivy

Is it possible to select multiple files in Kivy with a rectangle select? I'm using `FileChooserIconView` widget to select multiple files. This is my current section in `.kv` file:

```
FileChooserIconView:
   id: filechooser
   multiselect: True
   path: './'
   filters: ['*.png', '*.jpg', '*.jpeg']
```

I can choose multiple files but I have to click on each file individually. For my purposes it would be much more convenient to select many files like that:

[image: Drawing rectangle to select files]

My app use kivy 2.2.0.

Comment: What do you mean by the following: *'select multiple files in Kivy with a rectangle select?...'* ?

Comment: In many file choosers you can draw a rectangle on a list of files and the files that are in the rectangle are being selected. I'm not sure about the name of this pattern but I tried to show what I mean with the example with Lena's photos. The attached screen is from Windows file manager - not my application. I want to have this way of selecting files in my Kivy application.

Comment: Kivy is a gui not just an application as you mentioned. That being said, you can define whatever you want (within whatever is possible) using this toolkit and I believe the behavior you want can also be implemented.